# Exception when processing data during Kafka stream process

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am working on Kafka streams using the below code. I check a filter condition from a JSON obj for the condition if `"UserID":"1"`. Please refer the code below

```
builder.<String,String>stream(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), topic)
                   .filter(new Predicate <String, String>() {

               String userIDCheck = null;

               @Override
            public boolean test(String key, String value) {

                   try {
                       JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(value);

                       userIDCheck = jsonObj.get("UserID").toString();
                       System.out.println("userIDCheck: " + userIDCheck);                          
                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }

                   return userIDCheck.equals("1");
               }
            })
           .to(streamouttopic);
```

value : {"UserID":"1","Address":"XXX","AccountNo":"989","UserName":"Stella","AccountType":"YYY"}

I get the below error:

```
    Exception in thread "SampleStreamProducer-4eecc3ab-858c-44a4-9b8c-5ece2b4ab21a-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Exception caught in process. taskId=0_0, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=testtopic1, partition=0, offset=270
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:203)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.processAndPunctuate(StreamThread.java:679)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:557)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:527)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer / value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: unknown because key is null / value type: java.lang.String). Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:91)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:82)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamFilter$KStreamFilterProcessor.process(KStreamFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode$1.run(ProcessorNode.java:47)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:187)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:82)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:80)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:189)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to [B
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer.serialize(ByteArraySerializer.java:21)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.send(RecordCollectorImpl.java:76)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SinkNode.process(SinkNode.java:87)
```

Value and condition are fine from above stream code, i couldn't get why it is giving this exception during when executing steam code.

Comment: Can you share the whole stack trace? If it's truncated in the log, try to register an uncaught exception handler to get the full stack trace and the root cause.

Comment: Looks like, issue with Class Cast Exception . kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reported issue should only applies to Kafka 2.0 and older. Since 2.1.0 release, Kafka Streams supports "serde push down" and the `to()` operator should inherit the correct serdes from upstream (cf https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7456).

For Kafka 2.0 and older, you have to specify the correct Serdes for the `to()` operation, explicitly. Otherwise, it uses the default Serdes from the `StreamsConfig` that is `ByteArraySerde` (because the semantics or serde overwrite is a per operator "drop-in overwrite") -- and `String` cannot be cast to `byte[]`.

You need to do:

```java
.to(streamoutputtopic, Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
```

For even older versions (pre 1.0) that don't use `Produced` parameter yet, the code would be:

```java
.to(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), streamoutputtopic);
```

Comment: Produced cannot be resolved observed. I think, my version is different

Comment: older version should be `to(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), streamoutputtopic);` or similar

Comment: It works! Great! I have one last doubt. If i need to stream more than one topic, can I do like this? builder.stream(topic1).to(streamouttopic);  builder.stream(topic2).to(streamouttopic); builder.stream(topic3).to(streamouttopic);

Comment: Yes. That's possible -- What I am wondering: why do you not just try those things out if they work :)

Comment: I tried already and found it is working. Just want to confirm with experts like you! Thank you so much!